# Celery Worker sleep not working correctly

Tags: python, celery, sleep, worker

I have the next problem, I'm using a process on Python that must wait X number of second, the process by itself work correctly, the problem is when I put it as task on celery.

When the worker try to do the time.sleep(X) on one task it pause all the tasks in the worker, for example:

I have the Worker A, it can do 4 tasks at the same time (q,w,e and r), the task r have a sleep of 1800 seconds, so the worker is doing the 4 tasks at the same time, but when the r task do the sleep the worker stop q, w and e too.

Is this normal? Do you know how I can solve this problem?

EDIT: 
this is an example of  celery.py with my beat and queues

```
app.conf.update(
CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE='default',
CELERY_QUEUES=(
    Queue('search', routing_key='search.#'),
    Queue('tests', routing_key='tests.#'),
    Queue('default',    routing_key='tasks.#'),
),

CELERY_DEFAULT_EXCHANGE='tasks',
CELERY_DEFAULT_EXCHANGE_TYPE='topic',
CELERY_DEFAULT_ROUTING_KEY='tasks.default',
CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES=10,
CELERYD_TASK_SOFT_TIME_LIMIT=1800,
CELERY_ROUTES={
    'tests.tasks.volume': {
        'queue': 'tests',
        'routing_key': 'tests.volume',
    },
    'tests.tasks.summary': {
        'queue': 'tests',
        'routing_key': 'tests.summary',
    },
    'search.tasks.links': {
        'queue': 'search',
        'routing_key': 'search.links',
    },
    'search.tasks.urls': {
        'queue': 'search',
        'routing_key': 'search.urls',
    },
},

CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE={
    # heavy one
    'each-hour-summary': {
        'task': 'tests.tasks.summary',
        'schedule': crontab(minute='0', hour='*/1'),
        'args': (),
    },
    'each-hour-volume': {
        'task': 'tests.tasks.volume',
        'schedule': crontab(minute='0', hour='*/1'),
        'args': (),
    },
    'links-each-cuarter': {
        'task': 'search.tasks.links',
        'schedule': crontab(minute='*/15'),
        'args': (),
    },
    'urls-each-ten': {
        'schedule': crontab(minute='*/10'),
        'task': 'search.tasks.urls',
        'args': (),
    },
}
)
```

test.tasks.py

```
@app.task
def summary():
    execute_sumary() #heavy task ~ 1 hour aprox

@app.task
def volume():
    execute_volume() #no important ~ less than 5 minutes
```

and search.tasks.py

```
@app.task
def links():
    free = search_links() #return boolean
    if free:
        process_links()
    else:
        time.sleep(1080) #<--------sleep with which I have problems
    process_links()

@app.task
def urls():
    execute_urls() #no important ~ less than 1 minute
```

Well, I have 2 workers, A for the queue search and B for tests and defaul.

The problem is with A, when it take the task "links" and it execute the time.sleep() it stop the other tasks that the worker is doing.

Because the worker B is working correctly I thinks the problem is the time.sleep() function.

Comment: Can you provide a simple example or your code to understand better what is your question?

Comment: I put the part of the code with I have problems

Comment: I'm unsure why that happens however to fix your issue I would use `links.retry(countdown=1080)` unless you have some order you are trying to preserve

Comment: I tried use retry() but the problem is that I must wait after the search links() are done, I can't cancel and retry after, because the information may can change before the wait and I need the original, that information is save in local, if I cancel de task I'll lost the original information.

Answer (score 5):

If you only have one process/thread, call to sleep() will block it. This means that no other task will run...

Answer (score 1):

You set CELERYD_TASK_SOFT_TIME_LIMIT=1800 but your sleep is 1080.
Only one or two task can work in this time interval.
Set CELERYD_TASK_SOFT_TIME_LIMIT > (1080+(work time))*3
Set more --concurency (> 4) when start celery worker.